# REGEX to drop leading zero if followed by a character

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to format some strings in a `data.frame` and I would like to remove the leading zero if and only if the second character is a letter:

`3818119 --> 3818119`

`0M11936 --> M11936`

`0X11087 --> X11087`

`0T05060 --> T05060`

So far I have tried several approaches, last `gsub("^(?=[^A-Z]{2})","" ,output$id)` and `gsub("/^..[a-z]/","" ,output$id)` but all without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
sub("^0([[:alpha:]])", "\\1" ,output$id)
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `0` - a zero
- `([[:alpha:]])` - Group 1 (`\1`): a letter

If you want to only consider uppercase ASCII letters use

```
sub("^0([A-Z])", "\\1" ,output$id)
```

A lookaround version you tried to write requires the PCRE engine that is enabled with `perl=TRUE`:

```
sub("^0(?=[A-Z])", "", output$id, perl=TRUE)
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/MxgSSl):

```
x <- c("3818119", "0M11936", "0X11087", "0T05060")
sub("^0([[:alpha:]])", "\\1", x)
sub("^0([A-Z])", "\\1", x)
sub("^0(?=[A-Z])", "", x, perl=TRUE)
```

**NOTE** If there are multiple `0` chars at the start, add `+` after the `0`.

Comment: Great answer and great explanation, thanks a lot! I wasn't that far from the answer!

Comment: @sanna Please pay attention the note at the bottom of my answer. I decided to add this as a comment, and not as the main answer, because the requirement is "*only if the **second** character is a letter*". However, if the "second" means "what follows all leading zeros", you need to add `+` after the zero.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed it! Dziekuje!

Comment: @sanna Bardzo proszę :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you also want to remove multiple leading zeros in your string, then maybe you can try the code below

```
gsub("^0+([[:alpha:]].*)","\\1",s)
```

such that

```
> gsub("^0+([[:alpha:]].*)","\\1",s)
[1] "M11936" "M11936" "M11936" "01111"
```

**DATA**

```
s <- c("M11936","0M11936","00M11936","01111")
```

Comment: Why do you use `alnum` ? OP mentioned that they want to remove leading 0 `if and only if the second character is a letter`. This will also remove 0 if you have string like `01111`.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for reminder! I didn't notice that "if and only if the second character is a letter". The code is updated